# i18n library and switch_uri

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I've a problem with i18n library and switch_uri() function.
When I try to change the language, the link doesn't work.
I follow the guide to include the i18n library, and It works correctly with the words on menu for example, but doesn't work with links that should change the language.
Here is it my code:

VIEW

```
<?php echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('en'),'ENG')  ?>
<?php echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('it'),'ITA')  ?>
```

I tried to correct with BASE_URL but it did not work. How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance for your answers and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: "not working"... is very nice, would you like to share any error code you get and any steps you already tried to find the problem. Please also share the languages array you have in the lang library extension